# error: failed to push some refs to when pushing with a certain command

Tags: python, git, github, heroku, version-control

I keep getting this error when I do `git push -u origin master`
. git push works but that doesn't It's stuck with heroku too. When I do `git push heroku master` I get this same error message. All the answers on Stack Overflow say that it's because I didn't commit first but I did commit. I don't know what's wrong. If I don't solve this, I won't be able to follow along with my book and I'm tired of using the heroku GUI to push everything.

Comment: can you please add the output of the `git status` and `git remote -v` commands?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got ```heroku  https://git.heroku.com/mighty-beyond-77548.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/mighty-beyond-77548.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/Steve-Dusty/pages-app.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Steve-Dusty/pages-app.git (push)``` for git remote -v and ```"Your branch is up to date with "origin/main"```. for git status

Comment: from your outputs, for me if you want to push to origin (which is github), you simply use `git push` but right now you have nothing to push.

Comment: But I want to push to heroku though

Comment: Fixed, it's git push heroku MAIN not git push heroku MASTER.

Answer (score -1):

First thing: **never use `git push`** only until and unless you are 100% sure of which branch you are pushing to.

GitHub has a concept of default remote branch. so when you do `git push` you are actually pushing the code to the default branch.

You can check the default branch for your GitHub repository as below:

[image: Check default branch]

### Now coming to your doubt

If the branch you are currently in on local is different (other than the one you want to push to remotely) lets say `main`, then if you do `git push origin main` while being on the master branch, Git will try to push your local master branch to the remote master branch, and if local `master` branch is behind the remote `master` branch in terms of commit or if their is any discrepancies (maybe someone forced push something or did a rebase), then you will get the issue `error: failed to push some refs to when pushing with a certain command`

So there are two resolutions to it:

1. **recommended**: Change to the branch you want to push to remote repository, pull the changes from remote, resolve the conflicts if any, do the rebase and then push it to the remote
2. If you are 100% sure that your code from local is correct and you want to replace the remote branch completely with your local branch you can do a force push as `git push origin <BRANCH_NAME> -f`. But this is too dangerous, at times it can lead to code loss especially in big projects where multiple developers are working on the same repo